# Proving Set using the laws of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets. Prove the following set identity using the laws of set theory (set identities). So I am trying Justify each step with the law I used.

$A\cap(B\cup A')\cap B'=\emptyset$

And so my first thought would be using distributive law such as:

Distributive Law:

$A \cap (B \cup A^\prime) \cap B^\prime = ((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap A^\prime)) \cap B^\prime$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$(A\cap A')=\emptyset$$

All the steps below (to check your answer or if you give up ...)

> \begin{align}A \cap (B \cup A^\prime) \cap B^\prime &= ((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap A^\prime)) \cap B^ \prime &\text{(distribution)} \\ &= ((A\cap B)\cup\emptyset)\cap B' &\text{(inversion)} \\ &=  (A\cap B)\cap B' & \text{(identity)} \\ &=A\cap(B\cap B') & \text{(associativity)}\\ &=A\cap\emptyset &\text{(inversion)}\\ &=\emptyset &\text{(domination)} \\ \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First rearrange  $A\cap(B\cup A')\cap B'$ as $(A\cap B')\cap(B\cup A')$

Note that by [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), complement of $A\cap B'$, (first parentheses), is $B\cup A'$, (second parentheses). Now use: $A\cap A'=\emptyset$